# JS: simplest import not working! unexpected token export

Tags: javascript

**first.js**:

```js
export function multiply() {
    return 2 * 3;
}
```

**second.js**:

```js
import { multiply } from './first.js';

/*
const {multiply} = require('./first.js');
*/

const result = multiply();

console.log(`Result: ${result}`);
```

When I run it, I get

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

error.

If I try to only active the `require` import line, I get

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
```

error.

Comment: Your code works absolutely fine and I made it worked. Could you share your HTML?

Comment: In general, please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any such destructive edits will be reverted. Please see [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question) for more information on how deleting content works on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Updated files that work. Added `module.exports` to **math.js** and use `require` in **main.js**:

**math.js**:

```
function hello() {
     console.log("hello");
}

module.exports = {
    hello
}
```

**main.js**

```
const {hello} = require('./math.js');

hello();
```